# Batch file to copy the newest file created (not modified)

Tags: batch-file

I know there are a fair amount of questions about batch files copying the latest file. But I can't seem to find one that addresses my requirement.

I have a batch file...

```
(@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion) & (set myfolder_=Z:\myfolder1) & (for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /o:d /a:-d /b "!myfolder_!\*.mp3"') do (set latest_=!myfolder_!\%%~nxf)) & (if defined latest_ (echo rem latest file "!latest_!" & xcopy "!latest_!" "Z:\myfolder2" /V /D /Y) else (echo No designated files found in "!myfolder_!")) & (Pause) & (endlocal & goto :EOF)
```

It needs to copy across the latest file, by created date, but currently it seems to sort based on the modified date.

For example, if I modify the mp3 tag on an old file, this script appears to select and copy that file.

Note delayed expansion is on because I have to run this as a single line.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Have you tried adding /T:C to the dir command to select that date order is by creation date?

Comment: So `('dir /o:d /a:-d /b "!myfolder_!\*.mp3"')` would become `('dir /T:C /a:-d /b "!myfolder_!\*.mp3"')`?

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work:) Feel free to answer.

Comment: No, you need to indicate date order, and that the date to use is the creation date. So `dir /od /tc ....`

Comment: I'm confused now. What is the colon for in my script?

Comment: And does case matter?

Comment: OK I'm using `('dir /od /tc /a:-d /b "!myfolder_!\*.mp3"')`. I gained a loose understanding from [here](http://www.windows-commandline.com/dir-command-line-options/). Anyone interested. /od is order by date, /tc time created, /a:-d Exclude directories and /d list file-names without attributes. *.mp3, for my requirement makes it look for just mp3 files.

Comment: No case does not matter, just a personal way of writing code. And colons in dir are optional, so it can be `dir /od /tc /a-d /b` but this is my way of writing this kind of code. While allowed, if it works, use the format that makes you more confortable with your code. Yes the options does what you write, but not /d, it's /b in your command.

Comment: Great thanks. Yes /d should say /b in my explanation above. Thanks for pointing it out (too late to edit).

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer in case you find it helpful or leave feedback about it. See https://stackoverflow/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

Include `/TC` in `dir` command when parsing with `for /F`:

```
(@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion) & (set myfolder_=Z:\myfolder1) & (for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /TC /OD /A-D /B "!myfolder_!\*.mp3"') do (set latest_=!myfolder_!\%%~nxf)) & (if defined latest_ (echo rem latest file "!latest_!" & xcopy "!latest_!" "Z:\myfolder2" /V /D /Y) else (echo No designated files found in "!myfolder_!")) & (Pause) & (endlocal & goto :EOF)
```

should work.

> `/T`          Controls which time field displayed or used for sorting
>    `timefield`   `C`  Creation
>                `A`  Last Access
>                `W`  Last Written

From `dir /?` second help page.